# Git remote branch re-appears after deleting

Tags: git

Im trying to delete a remote branch and it keeps on re-listing. I have tried

1) git branch -rd origin/legacy
2) git gc --prune=now
3) git branch -d -r origin/legacy
4) When i try git remote rm origin/legacy
  I get error: Could not remove config section 'remote.origin/legacy'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To delete the branch from the remote repository, you need to do: `git push origin :branch-name`.  That's Git speak for remove `branch-name` from the remote repository.

Presumably, you have a reference to the remote branch locally (called `origin/branch-name`) and a local branch called `branch-name`.  `git remote prune origin` will remove all `origin/` references to branches that no longer exist, which will leave you with just the local branch.  You can delete that with `git branch -d branch-name`, if you like.

Comment: Awesome that worked! just seems counterintuitive to say git push origin :branch. not sure where i see remove or rm in that but thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, it seems a bit counterintuitive at first.  In general, `git push origin A:B` means to push local branch A to remote branch B.  So I treat `git push origin :B` as "push the empty reference it B" which removes B.  It's not a great way to think of it, but it's enough to help me remember. :-)